# Equality of two complex numbers with respect to argument

Tags: complex-numbers

If two complex numbers are equal , is it necessary that their arguments are also equal ? 
Is the vice versa also true ? means that if the arguments of two complex numbers are equal , does it necessarily imply that they’re equal? 
According to me , the first supposition would be right , but I’m not quite sure about the second one .

Comment: Hint:  what is the argument of any positive real number?

Comment: @lulu It’s $tan^{-1}|\frac{b}{a}|$

Comment: Neither $a$ nor $b$ appeared in my comment.  What is the argument of $3$?  What about $39$?

Comment: Oh for real numbers the argument is $0$ because they lie  on the real axis .

Comment: Well, for positive real numbers the argument is $0$.  Does that tell you what you need to know?

Comment: @lulu so you mean that it’s not necessary that if two complex numbers are equal they have the same argument ?

Comment: Not sure what you are saying,  Obviously equal numbers have equal arguments.  However my example gives two different complex numbers, $3,39$ as it happens, that have the same argument.  Nothing special about those numbers...any two positive reals would have worked.

Comment: @lulu sorry , I get your point now , that it’s not nexessary that if two complex numbers have the same argument then they’re equal. :)

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @lulu thanks for clarifying !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we take complex numbers as $z_1 = a+bi$ and $z_2 = c+di$, $z_1 = z_2$ if and only if $a = c$ and $b = d$. So $\arg(z_1) = \arg(z_2)$, obviously.

However, if $\arg(z_1) = \arg(z_2)$, it doesn't have to imply that $z_1 = z_2$. A simple counter-example is $z_1 = 2z_2$ with $z_1 \ne 0$. Their arguments are equal however $z_1 \ne z_2$ (if you know some about physics, you can think $z_1$ and $z_2$ as two vectors with same direction but different magnitudes. Then of course we can't say that they are equal).

Comment: thanks ! But please tell me , if the arguments of both the complex numbers are equal can we say that $z_1 = kz_2$ ?

Comment: Okay thank you very much !

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Ah wait a second, in your argument, if $k \le 0$, arguments are not the same. I was careless, sorry about that. For example if we take $z_1 = 1$ and $z_2 = -1$, $\arg(z_1) = 0$ while $\arg(z_2) = \pi$.

Comment: It’s alright ! I actually meant it for $k>0$ . Just forgot to mention it. :)